# Execute bash script as root from normal user

Tags: sudo

I am trying to execute a bash script as root from a normal user. The story behind is that I need the www-data user to be able to kill a specific process. To avoid having apache being able to go mayhem on processes I've created the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(pgrep mono)
kill -9 $PID
```

To be able to perform this, I have done an `apt-get install sudo` and then with `visudo` added the following line to the bottom of the file

```
myuser ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/script/foo.sh
```

But when I sign into myuser and try to run `/path/to/script/foo.sh` I receive the following error `-bash: /path/to/script/foo.sh: Permission denied`

The current permission of the file are as follows

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   48 Nov  7 12:11 foo.sh
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

To use sudo, you need to prefix your command with "sudo".
ie:

```
$ sudo /path/to/script/foo.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Login with root and do the following:

```
cd /path/to/script

chmod u+x foo.sh

./foo.sh
```

Test to see if the program runs.
Now switch to myuser,

```
su myuser
```

and try to run the program again:

```
/path/to/script/foo.sh
```